# What countries are calling for a ceasefire between Israel and Hamas in 2021?

Tags: international-relations, israel, palestine, armed-conflict, peace-treaty

Because of the ongoing hostilities between Israel and Hamas, multiple countries have said they are interested in making a peace treaty. What countries have called for the hostilities to stop?

To clarify, I am talking only about the current hostilities going on, not about making a formal peace treaty. Countries that want a formal peace treaty would also answer the question though because a formal peace treaty would end current hostilities if signed. Also, a country calling for restraint (e.g. saying to minimize civilian casualties) does not call for the hostilities to stop. Calling for the hostilities to stop means saying that *you want the fighting to stop*.

Comment: Pretty much all countries are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple media sources have recently reported that the US has blocked
a Security Council (SC) resolution calling for an immediate end to the
hostilities:

> US blocks UN Security Council statement on Israel-Palestine violence
>
> Nixed statement 'expressed deep concern about the latest situation
> in Gaza, and called for an immediate' end to hostilities
>
> [US blocks UN Security Council statement on Israel-Palestine violence](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/world/us-blocks-un-security-council-statement-on-israel-palestine-violence/2239211)

The other members of the SC are: China, France, Russia, United
Kingdom, Estonia, India, Ireland, Kenya, Mexico, Niger, Norway, Saint
Vincent and the Grenadies, Tunisia, and Vietnam. According to the
Times of Israel, they were ready to issue a joint statement calling
for an immediate ceasefire:

> Fourteen of the 15 Security Council members sought to issue a joint
> statement, which requires unanimous approval, after closed emergency
> meetings on Monday and Wednesday. They were rebuffed by the US,
> which said it wanted more time for its own diplomatic efforts to
> play out, according to several Security Council diplomats. That
> statement too would have called for an immediate ceasefire, while
> condemning both sides for the violence.
>
> [For 3rd time, US blocking joint Security Council statement urging ceasefire](https://www.timesofisrael.com/for-3rd-time-us-blocking-joint-security-council-statement-urging-ceasefire/)

In addition to the 14 SC members, others have also called for an
immediate ceasefire:

- [Egypt's President Abdel Fattah al-Sisi](https://www.i24news.tv/en/news/israel/diplomacy-defense/1621262924-ceasefire-between-israel-hamas-absolutely-necessary-says-france-s-macron-egypt-s-sisi)
- [Finland's UN representative Jukka Salovaara](https://valtioneuvosto.fi/en/-/statement-by-finland-united-nations-security-council-open-debate-on-middle-east) ("A ceasefire needs to be implemented without any delay")
- [Germany's Foreign Minister Heiko Maas](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/divisions-curb-eu-peacemaking-role-israel-gaza-violence-2021-05-18/)
- [Jordan's Deputy Prime Minister Ayman Safadi](https://www.un.org/press/en/2021/sc14521.doc.htm)

Just now it was reported that EUs 27 foreign ministers have met in
a videoconference to discuss and possibly adopt a joint declaration
about the situation:

> “I think I’m not being too optimistic (to say) that at a minimum, what will probably come out (of Tuesday’s EU meeting) is *the call for a ceasefire*, an offer of humanitarian aid and then seeing how to restart the political process,” Bartolo said.
>
> [Israel-Palestine: EU foreign ministers to call for ceasefire](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/5/18/israel-palestine-eu-foreign-ministers-to-call-for-ceasefire)

Evarist Bartolo is currently serving as the EUs Minister of Foreign
Affairs. The joint declaration appears to have been blocked by
Hungary:

> EU foreign policy chief Josep Borrell called for the *implementation of a ceasefire*, following a video conference of EU foreign ministers, adding that the call was backed by all the bloc’s member states except Hungary.
>
> [Israel continues Gaza air raids as calls for ceasefire grow: Live](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2021/5/18/israel-shells-lebanon-as-biden-continues-push-for-gaza-ceasefire)

So to the list of countries calling for a ceasefire, we should add the other 26 EU member states: Austria,
Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Lithuania,
Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia,
Slovenia, Spain, and Sweden.